# Filter rows from a CSV file if row values are found in another CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I found three questions giving a basis but I couldn't create a code for this work, I would like some help because I really couldn't create and I think it can be very useful for other people in the future. I'll leave the three questions I tried to work on:

[Filter rows in csv file based on another csv file and save the filtered data in a new file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302079/filter-rows-in-csv-file-based-on-another-csv-file-and-save-the-filtered-data-in)
[Python how to search value in one csv based on another csv - pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66049426/python-how-to-search-value-in-one-csv-based-on-another-csv-pandas)
[Python: Filtering CSV with conditions from another CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578972/python-filtering-csv-with-conditions-from-another-csv)

**Data explanation:**

`CSV` file name `"Main.csv"`:

```
label,value,market
,,
team1 v team2,match1,market1
team3 v team4,match2,market2
team5 v team6,match3,market3
```

`CSV` file name `"parameter.csv"`: used as a parameter for the filter:

```
time,goals,label,value
,,,
15,4,team1 v team2,match1
10,3,team5 v team6,match3
```

> RULE: If the value of `label` and `value` are found exactly together in a row, so be present in the `CSV`
> final!

`CSV` expected and created after filter:

```
label,value,market
,,
team1 v team2,match1,market1
team5 v team6,match3,market3
```

Comment: If the values as switched, is it still a match? `team1 v team2` matches `team2 v team1`?

Comment: Hi @tdelaney No, it needs to be perfectly the value, totally equal.

Comment: if value is ```team1 v team2``` then it should only match if the value of the other csv is ```team1 v team2```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code with Pandas (I have added some comments for explanation):

```
import pandas as pd

#load the files to dataframes
main = pd.read_csv("Main.csv")
par = pd.read_csv("parameter.csv")

#transform the dataframes to lists of dictionaries
main_dict=main.to_dict(orient='records')
par_dict=par.to_dict(orient='records')

#create a list of dictionaries that use only 'label' and 'value' as keys
par_dict = [{'label':i['label'], 'value':i['value']} for i in par_dict]

#search for records in main that the pair of label-value exists in the previous list
result = [i for i in main_dict if {'label':i['label'], 'value':i['value']} in par_dict]

#change back to dataframe and save to csv
result=pd.DataFrame(result)

result.to_csv('resut.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I have to thank you enormously for all the work you were willing to do to help me!

Comment: Welcome, happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily with pandas by setting the common columns as index to the dataframes. Since you don't care about the other columns in `parameter.csv`, they can be dropped.

```
import pandas as pd
common_index = ["label", "value"]
main = pd.read_csv("Main.csv").dropna().set_index(common_index)
param = (pd.read_csv("parameter.csv", usecols=common_index)
    .dropna().set_index(common_index))
result = main[main.index.isin(param.index)]
print(result)
```

Result

```
                      market
label         value          
team1 v team2 match1  market1
team5 v team6 match3  market3
```

Comment: It must match value column too

Comment: @IoaTzimas - missed that, will fix.

Comment: @IoaTzimas - okay, using a mutliindex instead.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done in the standard library using the `csv` module. Create a set from the columns of interest in the parameters file and use that as a filter when reading the main file.

```
import csv
with open("parameter.csv", newline="") as p_file:
    reader = csv.reader(p_file)
    next(reader)
    param_set = {tuple(row[2:4]) for row in reader if row[2]}

with open("Main.csv") as m_file:
    reader = csv.reader(m_file)
    next(reader)
    result = [row for row in reader if tuple(row[0:2]) in param_set]

print(result)
```